# Stretch div upon print function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function which works great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(printpage)
{
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
return false;
}
</script>
```

However my div is about half of the paper size. Is there a way to make my div stretch to a full paper size when the function is called?

Comment: Why all that trouble instead of a simple print stylesheet?

Comment: @PeeHaa I tried to search for prinst stylesheet but couldn't find any good information on how to setup one. So how do you make one?

Comment: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

Comment: @PeeHaa That seem to work. But in my case it becomes really messy. I would have to resize like 50 elements in print.css to make them scale properly. I there a easier way?

Comment: There might be, but the above always worked for me. Maybe somebody else will have some options for you.